# Is there any possibility to use custom labels inside Rich Text Area field in Salesforce objects?

Tags: sobject, customlabel, richtextarea

Hi I want to know whether custom labels in salesforce can be used in rich text area field in salesforce objects ? If possible any suggestions or workaround to achieve the same functionality would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds a bit like an XY problem. Why do you want to use custom labels inside of a rich text area field? Is it a matter of setting a default?

Comment: This would be useful when adding links in a rich text field, so that the URL stays consistent with the tier it was launched from.  Referencing either a custom label, custom setting, or custom metadata could make the base portion of the URL be specific to the environment.